# What is the best approach to handle file upload in graphql?

Tags: file-upload, graphql, prisma

I'm looking for a way to handle file upload in my backend powered by prisma (graphcool). However I am a beginner and it looks very intimidating and I don't know anything about how file upload works. What is the best aproach to do this ? Can I do it using prisma ? I have red about Amazon S3 buckets but it looks like a complicated approach to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this.  I will lay out a few solutions and resources and you should have something to get you going.

Two common ways to handle this primarily differ in the method used to **persist** the uploaded files, upload directly to the server **file system** vs. upload to a **cloud service**, typically S3.

For most use cases, the second option, uploading to a cloud service will be superior due to ease of scalability, ease of backing up data in something like S3 and additional security features such as signed urls.  One more neat thing about using S3 in particular is that you can take advantage of [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/), described (by AWS) as

> an interactive query service that makes it easy to analyze data in Amazon S3 using standard SQL

Note that the examples below all leverage the awesome work by [Jayden Seric](https://github.com/jaydenseric), who has done tons of work on uploads using GraphQL.

- [Upload to FS, API and react example](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples): Upload files to node server file system
- [middleware for apollo-upload-server](https://github.com/homeroom-live/graphql-middleware-apollo-upload-server): small abstraction on top of `apollo-upload-server` which simplifies server development.  This example also shows how to integrate with S3.